# rename folders with a matching list file

Tags: bash, rename, matching

Given the matching file `matching.txt`, how can one rename a series of folders together in shell command.

The example of the matching file:

```
a1  b2
a2  b11
a3  b24
a4  b23
...
```

According to `matching.txt`, all the folders' names listed in the first column should be changed to the names in the second.
Many thanks for any input!

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. You're expected to include an attempt to have solved your problem or at least a discussion of why you are stuck. Update with something and people will jump in to help. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter People will answer anyway :(

Comment: Why not helping people if it requires 10s of thinking? I would only ignore the request if the problem is too complex.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca : Each to his own. After  you've spent 10K+ time answering the same question over and over, you might think differently (This Q at least is slightly different) I upvote your wonderfully correct and concise answer. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: I agree that above a certain threshold (number of Q answered), one is no more interested in being involved. Still, the effort of building a question in an organized and clear manner is to be appreciated. Ideally, we should provide the exact solution posted somewhere else on SO. Cheers. SO is a joyful place.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=' '
while read a b; do
    # Skip the directory if it does not exist
    [ -d "$a" ] || continue
    mv "$a" "$b"
done <matching.txt
```